# Prove that {x ∈ Z : x ≡ 4 (mod 6)} ⊂ {x ∈ Z : x ≡ 0 (mod 2)}.

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Let A:{x ∈ Z : x ≡ 4 (mod 6)} and B:{x ∈ Z : x ≡ 0 (mod 2)}.

We have to show that A ⊂ B, meaning that all elements of A are in B but B contains at least one element that is not in A.

I know that x ≡ 4 (mod 6) means that 6|(x-4) by definition of congruency. Then by definition of divisibility: x-4=6y for some y∈Z.

Similarly, 2|x and so x=2m for some m∈Z.

Note that: x=4+6y or x=2(2+3y)

Consequently, x=2n where n is the integer (2+3y)

We have x=2n and x=2m. By definition of evenness, x is even.

We have A is the set of all even integers and B is also the set of all even integers.

Hence, we can conclude that all elements of A are in B.

> I was wondering how I can show that B contains at least one element that is not in A to finally prove that A is a proper subset of B.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what level of detail you need, but a more succinct version of your proof is that an element $x \in A$ is the sum of $4$ and a multiple of $6$, both of which are even, so $x$ is even. Then apply Parcly's answer to show proper inclusion.

You want to be careful. Although every element of $A$ is even, $A$  is not the set of even integers, as Parcly's answer shows.

Answer (score 3):

$0\in B$ but $0\not\in A$. This immediately shows proper inclusion.